# How do I get the symbols for OpenGL?

Tags: debugging, opengl

I am getting an unhandled exception in opengl32.dll (version 10.0.10586.0) while using Octave. Since I am given the option to debug, I do so opening VS2015. As expected opengl32.pbd is not loaded, so I try to load the symbols from the Microsoft symbol servers. I get the message that opengl.pdb could not be found in the selected paths. Since this DLL is a Microsoft product I would assume their server would have the symbols. Where can I get the pbd file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since this DLL is a Microsoft product I would assume their server would have the symbols. Where can I get the pbd file?

In the case of opengl32.dll a symbols file would be of little use, because opengl32.dll is merely a wrapper into which the actual OpenGL implementations that are provided by the graphics drivers are hooking into. Any crash happening inside OpenGL context will happen in the driver's code.

However OpenGL drivers are particularly complex beasts. Any crash happening in OpenGL is likely because the host program misuses the API. For example passing in a pointer to a buffer that's to short or calling a function that's meant to read from a so called "buffer object", without a buffer object actually bound to the respective data source (=buffer target in OpenGL terminology).

Comment: You have made some good points. Sounds like I probably don't have the knowledge to debug OpenGL or Octave, even with the symbols. I have reported the Octave crash to the developers, but they seem to be having trouble replicating the bug, so I was trying to get more info to pass onto them.

Comment: @spainchaud: Do you have a bugtracking ID or similar? I'd like to take a look at it.

Comment: bug #48741: Octave crashes on call to imagesc